# Closing gremlin cluster connections created from AWS lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I have a java lambda that is creating a gremlin cluster:

```
cluster = Cluster.build()
        .addContactPoints(shuffled.toArray(new String[endpoints.length]))
        .port(Integer.parseInt(port))
        .serializer(new GryoMessageSerializerV1d0(GryoMapper.build().addRegistry(JanusGraphIoRegistry.getInstance())))
        .maxConnectionPoolSize(4096)
        .maxSimultaneousUsagePerConnection(4096)
        .maxInProcessPerConnection(4096)
        .maxWaitForConnection(30000)
        .create();
```

I am then creating a Traversal with this:

```
final DriverRemoteConnection connection = DriverRemoteConnection.using(cluster).;

final GraphTraversalSource g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal().withRemote(connection);
```

Here is my problem, Creating the cluster is expensive and I would like to only do this once per lambda creation and reuse it if the lambda is reused. If I construct the cluster either statically or with a singleton, it will get reused, but when the lambda dies after 5 minutes per AWS max lambda life the connections created from the cluster are not closed and stay open forever on the Gremlin Server.

Comment: Are you concerned about connections left open on the Gremlin Server side? I don't know the life cycle of AWS lambdas, but I'd assume that once the max lambda life is exceeded the connections are destroyed on that side - correct?

Comment: That is what I would have expected, but I am now unclear on the lifecycle of the lambda. From what I understood is the jvm would be destroyed when the lambda timeout is reached. In testing connections locally, not in a lambda, when the JVM goes away so does the connection on the Gremlin Server. But when the cluster connection is made from a lambda the connection stays forever.

Comment: @JaradDuersch do you have any progress there?

Answer (score 0):

A trick that I found useful to ensure the Gremlin cluster is closed in the end of your application lifecycle is ShutdownHooks:

```
/**
 * Close the clusters held by {@link #ClusterSingleton}. Be aware that the shutdown hooks are not ensured to be executed.
 * For instance:
 * <ol>
 *     <li><code>kill -9</code>: DON'T run the shutdown hook</li>
 *     <li><code>kill -2</code>: Usually run the shutdown hook</li>
 *     <li><code>kill -15</code>: Usually run the shutdown hook</li>
 *     <li><code>CTRL + c</code>: Usually run the shutdown hook</li>
 * </ol>
 */
private static class CloseClusterOnShutdownHook extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Cluster cluster = ClusterSingleton.getInstance()
        try {
            // Not using logger because it may not work during JVM shutdown
            System.out.println("Closing Gremlin Cluster: " + cluster.allHosts());
            cluster.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("An exception occurred while closing cluster " + cluster);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You can add the ShutdownHook this way:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new CloseClusterOnShutdownHook());
```